# Easiest way for closed kinematic chain?

Tags: ros, ros2, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings.

I have a model containing a closed kinematic chain, which is not supported by ROS URDF file standard. Therefore I could write the description also in SDF which allows closed kinematic chains, however, I am not certain if I could use something like XACRO to parametrize the SDF similar to an URDF.

Alternatively, is it possible to use the `<gazebo>` tag in the context of the URDF for the definition of the joints which close the kinematic chain?

**TL;DR**

- I have a closed kinematic chain
  within a robot configuration.
- Is it possible to parametrize the
  SDF which allows for the closed
  kinematic chain?
- Is it possible the achieve the closed
  kinematic chain with the use of the
  `<gazebo>` tag within the URDF?
- Is there a fast, straight forward way
  to get a parametrizable robot
  description for closed kinematic
  chains?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404825/easiest-way-for-closed-kinematic-chain?/) by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Yes, you could use xacro to parse a parameterized SDF file directly if you want, either using extensions of the base xacro tool (e.g. https://github.com/gezp/xacro4sdf) or with a little copy paste (or scripting) of the generated output
- Yes, you can use Xacro with `<gazebo>` tags to create closed kinematic chains that would function in gazebo when the generated URDF gets converted to SDF. This might be a useful example: https://github.com/2b-t/closed_loop/blob/humble/urdf/closed_loop.urdf.xacro
- Fast and straightforward is a bit arbitrary... depends a bit on your needs and what you're starting with. I'd recommend using the "standard" xacro->urdf->sdf pipeline so your description file remains compatible with other tools like RViz without requiring duplicate definitions. Adding the gazebo tags isn't too cumbersome.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on 2022-08-10**:
Thank you very much! As you, I prefer the approach with `<gazebo>` tags, so I have only one file to maintain.